# disable a dynamically added control

Tags: jquery

here is the code that works just fine to create my controls

```
function mycallback(data) {

    $.each(data.user, function (i,data) {

        $("<div>"+data.id+"</div>").attr('id',data.id).appendTo('#page_14_14');

        var ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'text', value:data.email , id:data.id }).addClass("text");
         $(ctrl).appendTo("#"+data.id); 
       document.getElementById(data.id).disable;
    });
}
```

but I want my text input zone to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.user, function (i,data) {
   $("<div>"+data.id+"</div>").attr('id',data.id).appendTo('#page_14_14');
   var ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'text', value:data.email , id:data.id }).addClass("text");
   $(ctrl).appendTo("#"+data.id); 
   document.getElementById(data.id).disable; // this won't work
   $('#' + data.id).prop('diasabled', true);  // this will
});
```

Comment: what is the id of the element you want to disable??  data.id  is given to the id of a DIV element , you can't disable a DIV element ,  if there is another control somewhere with the same id then you need to re-design to not use duplicate id's  .    Can you explain more?

Comment: i want to disable the text input zone and yes the div and the input both have data.id as id good point there im going to try to change the text input id

Comment: i think it works but does the disable property make the input zone dissapear? if so what is the property that makes it inchangable but yet visible plz

Comment: .prop('disabled' , false);   will reverse and make the input usable again